# Ubuntu 22.04 Failed to execute child process

Tags: 22.04, ssd

I just install ubuntu 22.04 on an external SSD (Samsung t7), on my laptop (Asus G512) and it works fine but after a while suddenly it crashed like bellow image:

[image]

which is weird because I do SMART test and repair it, so I'm pretty sure this is not SSD hardware issue.

so now there are some questions.

1. Is it a good idea to have Linux on an external SSD for daily use?
2. Is my hardware/Laptop having issues after a long time?
3. Finally, Is there a solution or idea for the problem?

Comment: No, it's not ideal to have it on a USB disk, but it should work. Have you checked the disk for errors? You can boot Ubuntu off a live USB key and use that to check the disk. Is it full? You didn't tell us the size or anything, or how it's connected, or any important relevant details.

Comment: No, it's a 1T SSD and uses usb3 for connection with 1000MB/s w/r speed which is very fast actually I tested that and install applications like android studio it works just like internal, But the only problem is this crashing. and please could you told me why this not ideal to have linux on external

Comment: I did say "it should work"! Have you checked the disk for errors as I suggested?